# Emulating a Forza telemetry server and/or an OBD Bluetooth adapter (in Python)

Tags: networking, python, pygame

I'm making a driving game in Pygame, and want to give a player the option to send game data to a Forza-compatible dashboard app (like SIM Dashboard) or to an OBD app (like RevHeadz). How do I do so?
Info that should be sent: current gear, RPM, and speed

Comment: Do you need to upload post-game stats & data to a server? If so, [`requests`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) could be a good starting point to implement a solution on your own. Please note that GameDev is intended for helping resolve existing issues, not suggesting plain solutions for your own projects. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @lliggorgio No, I found am ELM327 emulator which solved my problem temporarily (PyInstaller breaks the function).

Comment: Despite being a temporary solution, that could be eligible for an answer to your question. Someone else may consider it a starting point and propose a different solution. Mind writing it down?

Comment: @liggiorgio I tried sending UDP packets but SIM Dashboard doesn't recognize my game as a telemetry server. My game: https://github.com/sserver224/Car-Racing-3D/blob/main/car_racing_3d.py